# Bounded function in $L_1([0,\infty))$ but not in $L_2([0,\infty))$

Tags: lp-spaces

Is it possible to find a continuous bounded function $f$ such that the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx
\end{equation}
is finite and the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|^2dx
\end{equation}
diverges?

**Edit**
What happens if we drop the boundedness condition? Is it possible to find a function satisfying these two conditions?

Comment: It is also a very interesting problem to *find* such a function if you drop the boundedness condition.

Comment: Ah, I see you asked for bounded functions. Note that $L^\infty \cap L^1 \subset \bigcap\limits_{p \in [1,\infty]} L^p.$ (For you can write $|f|^p \leq c^{p-1} |f|$ for $c$ a bound of $|f|$ and $p > 1.$)

Comment: @StinkingBishop that is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is bounded, then $\left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert^2\leqslant \left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert \sup_{t\geqslant 0}\left\lvert f(t)\right\rvert$ hence for a bounded function, integrability implies square integrability.

If $f$ is not bounded, everything can happen: let $f_n$ be the function whose graph is the polygonal line linking the points $(0,0)$, $ (n-1/n^2,0)$, $(n,\sqrt n)$, $(n+1/n^2,0)$ and $f_n(t)=0$ for $t>n+1/n^2$. Defining $f=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}f_n$, the uniform convergence of the series on $[0,R]$ holds for each $R$, hence $f$ is continuous. Since the support of the $f_n$ are disjoint, the following equality holds for $p\in\{1,2\}$:
$$
\int_0^\infty \lvert f(t)\rvert^pdt=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\int_0^\infty \lvert f_n(t)\rvert^pdt
$$
and we can see that $f$ is integrable but not $f^2$.

Comment: How is it if we drop the boundedness condition as mentioned by Stinking Bishop in his comment?

Comment: @TooManyQuestionsInLife then you find an example as the ones I told you before.

Comment: Normally, it is better to ask followup question in a separated question, otherwise it is without end (since it is your first question on this site, you probably did not know this so I addressed it).

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thank you for your answer and the hint regarding followup questions.

Comment: You are welcome!